# Event accessing Bitmap while its locked

Tags: c#, events, bitmap, thread-safety, aforge

I am trying to capture webcam frames from AForge.Net in C#. Unfortunetaly I get an ArgumentException at _CurrentFrame.LockBits. I suppose there is a problem with my event writing to the locked Bitmap!? Sometimes I also get "A generic error occurred in GDI+" at UnlockBits.

```
public bool GetFrame(ref Draw.STexture Frame)
{
    BitmapData bd = _CurrentFrame.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, _CurrentFrame.Width,  _CurrentFrame.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    byte[] data = new byte[4 * _CurrentFrame.Width * _CurrentFrame.Height];
    Marshal.Copy(bd.Scan0, data, 0, data.Length);
    //Do something with data here
    _CurrentFrame.UnlockBits(bd);
    _CurrentFrame.Dispose();
}

private void OnFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs e)
{
    if (_CurrentFrame != null)
        _CurrentFrame.Dispose();
    _CurrentFrame = (Bitmap)e.Frame.Clone();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bitmap.Clone() method is dangerous, it creates a shallow copy of the bitmap.  That copy stores the pointer to the pixel data instead of copying the pixels.  In most camera drivers,  that pointer will only be valid while the callback (event) runs.  If you try to use it later then you'll be accessing invalid pixel data, making an exception on LockBits highly likely.

Either do the processing *while* the event runs or create a deep copy with the Bitmap(Image) constructor.  That copy tends to be expensive of course.